# can serializers.serialize consolidate/concatenate more than one object of different types

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a person and company classes in my models.py

In the view I'm doing the following:

```
company = company.objects.filter(company_id=compid)
user = person.objects.filter(person_id=company[0].manager_id)
```

I wish to enter all the fields of company and user into one output and return the result like so:

```
output = serializers.serialize('json',[company,user], fields=('company_id', 'company_name', 'user_id', 'user_name'))
return HttpResponse(output, content_type="application/json")
```

how can this result be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `serializers.serialize`, I think get a `ValuesQuerySet` first is more **flexiable**, and you can use cross model query in fields:

```
companys = company.objects.filter(...)
output = list(company.values('id',
        'name', 'manager__id', 'manager__name'))
json.dumps(output)
```

Note **two `_`** between them.